# How do I search a column of data for a specific number in excel?

Tags: excel

I have 3 columns of about 100,000 data points in each excel file and I need to search for a specific number in one of these columns. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can use MATCH() for that.

Comment: Please familiarise yourself with this site by taking the [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in columns J, K, L, you are looking for the number '5' and that the number only appears once. you can use the below formula to get the cell reference

```
=IFERROR(ADDRESS(MATCH(5,J:J,0),COLUMN(J1)),IFERROR(ADDRESS(MATCH(5,K:K,0),COLUMN(L1)),ADDRESS(MATCH(5,L:L,0),COLUMN(L1))))
```